# Access denied when attempting to download a tar.gz file using requests

Tags: python, download, python-requests

I have a very large number of URLs, each directs to a downloadable tar.gz file containing a .csv file.

If I manually put any of the addresses into Firefox, a popup immediately shows asking if I'd like to save or directly open the file - both work fine.

If I use requests simply as:

```
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.content)
```

The following and more is printed:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>5F59....
```

Is it possible to automate downloading all of these files with Python as it can be done manually without any authorisation?

**Edit:**

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r)
```

outputs:

```
<Response [403]>
```

**Edit 2:**

I can also download the file with `wget` from my terminal, but get

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

when using [Python's wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use request.urlretrieve.
I have the same problem. Also when try to open link, get this error 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it'

But than I read this article https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/data-transfer-process-with-python-999b6cbcd7ea
Now my code is like:

```
url = 'https://sitename.s3.amazonaws.com/csv_exports/74d6d645-7796ea89f8/f2038f62d459.csv.gz'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
#Download file to computer
urlrtv = request.urlretrieve(url=url, filename=f'C:\\Users\\Path\\Downloads\\test.csv.gz')
```

And It works. I'm newby in python so i can't explain how it works explicitly, but it works for me. maybe it will help you.